# This JSON string won't get deserialized

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We're trying to deserialize the following JSON string:

```
string responseData = "{\"status\":\"2000\",\"data\":[{\"response\":{\"TrxId\":4972783,\"result\":1,\"accruedPoints\":null}}],\"error\":null}";


var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, object>>(responseData);
object value, error, oData;

dic.TryGetValue("status", out value);
dic.TryGetValue("data", out oData);
string status = Convert.ToString(value);
string data = Convert.ToString(oData);
Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
```

We're facing problems deserializing `data`. Following is the exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Is there a better way to deserialize this JSON object?
We need the `accruedPoints` value.

Comment: Your JSON does not look directly dictionary compatible at first glance. Why should you cast it to Dictionary?

Comment: So what do you suggest. How should this be done ?

Comment: @Amit I tried using List<String>. This is what  I get: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 2, position 3.

Comment: Deserialize into a custom object with same field names.

Comment: You need to first deserialize it to an array before trying to access the first object of the array. The value corresponding the the tag "data" is encapsulated in [ ], so it is an array not a JSONObject which is enclosed in { }

Comment: See the answer due to which this one is marked duplicate. You can copy this `{"status":"2000","data":[{"response":{"TrxId":4972783,"result":1,"accruedPoints":null}}],"error":null}` and paste as classes in visual studio and your classes will be created. I have formatted it correctly so that direct paste into visual studio will generate classes.

Comment: When you generate classes, deserialize to Rootobject, and get accrued points as `Convert.ToString(root.data[0].response.accruedPoints);`

Comment: Once your classes are generated, this code works.           `string responseData = "{\"status\":\"2000\",\"data\":[{\"response\":{\"TrxId\":4972783,\"result\":1,\"accruedPoints\":null}}],\"error\":null}";
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseData);
            Console.WriteLine(root.data[0].response.accruedPoints);
            Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: @amit Json2csharp couldn't generate the classes.

Comment: You don't have visual studio?

Comment: `public class Rootobject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public object error { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int TrxId { get; set; }
        public int result { get; set; }
        public object accruedPoints { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: These are your classes. Just format it correctly.